# erro na session CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho um menu dinâmico que faz uma busca no banco e preenche esse menu, quando estou na home ele funciona normalmente porém quando mudo de pagina o valor retorna nulo e gera erro no `count()`, percebi que sempre que mudo de pagina a tabela `ci_session` atualiza no banco, nunca mexi com o `codeIgniter` antes e não sei se isso é normal. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
$redes = $this->session->userdata('redes');
                            if(!empty($redes)) {
                                if (count($redes) > 0) {
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($redes); $i++) {
                                        echo '<li class="skew-25"><a href="' . $redes[$i]['url'] . '" target="_blank" data-title="' . $redes[$i]['titulo'] . '" data-tooltip="true"><span class="fa ' . $redes[$i]['class'] . ' skew25"></span></a></li>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```